# Compiled typescript-code can`t see imported styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I`m using typescript files together with css files in /client folder and compile them into /dist folder.
When i try to build project using compiled js code, i get an error:

> Can't resolve './App.css' in '/Users/{username}/Documents/myApp/dist/modules/App'

because css files stay at client folder.
I tried to use copyfiles package, but it copies css files into separate folder /client into /dist folder. I want every css file was in the same folder as every react-component.
For example, i have a folder Footer with .tsx file and .css file, which is imported by .tsx. And i want the same structure in /dist folder, but instead i get a /client folder in dist where only .css files are located.

I use style-loader and css-loader for loading styles in webpack.

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: How are you importing your CSS? What are you using to bundle it? Is it just the TypeScript compiler or are you using something like Webpack?

Comment: @MikeC i edited description.

Comment: To import properly, you need to use something like `typings-for-css-modules-loader`.